# Making R data frame dynamic like excel

Tags: r, dynamic

I am trying to mimic an excel sheet for inventory modelling, where values of cells changes dynamically based on the values of other cells.
However this is not happening in R.

For example if I have a `data.frame` and I say

```
x <- data.frame(a = 5, b = 6)
```

and then

```
x$c <- a + b
```

so c should be 11.
However when I change `a` to say 1 instead of 5, `c` is not changed to 7. The problem is that I have many columns that needs to by dynamic to each other, is there a package that mimics this like excel?

Thanks in advance.
Haytham

Comment: why not just rerun the code when you update the dataframe?

Comment: Simply define variable values at the beginning of your script. Then below that everything that should change automatically based on the input above, and rerun the whole code as @Mike said every time your variable values change.

Comment: The usual workflow in R is that you write a function that does all necessary calculations and accepts your data.frame as input. If your data.frame changes, you simply rerun the function with the new input. That's not so different to what Excel is doing. However, it is not a design goal of R package developers to mimic Excel. The answer to your question is probably "No."

Comment: Hi Mike and Roland, the problem is that when I re-run the code the values changed dynamically meaning the the second inout will affect the first input again and again .its basically a simulation where every thing interacts together simultaneously where every row is a day and it affects the next day after it and so on. the input is created by the dynamics.

Comment: Hi LAP , I will try again as you say but I did try it before it did not bring the same results simply because when I do the second column as a loop it changes the first loop and so on but may be there is a specific sequence I can reach to get it right . however it is strange that r as big as it is does not have this dynamic functionality.